# Why 'bundler gem' adds 'rake' and 'rspec' to Gemfile and not to .gemspec file as a development dependencies?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, gemspecs

I am not well familiar with Ruby world. Java build tools usually use **test scope** for things like jUnit.

I initialized a new project with command: `bundle gem new_gem_from_bundler` and the content of `Gemfile` is

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

# Specify your gem's dependencies in new_gem_from_bundler.gemspec
gemspec

gem "rake", "~> 12.0"
gem "rspec", "~> 3.0"
```

Why not:

```
group :development do
  gem "rspec", "~> 3.9.0"
  gem "rake", "~> 3.0"
end
```

Also since there is a `.gemspec` file I would expect `rake` and `rspec` to be defined like this:

```
spec.add_development_dependency 'rake', '~> 12.0'
spec.add_development_dependency 'rspec', '~> 3.0'
```

Why are they declared as a regular 'gem' dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

Bundler uses template files for creating new gems. You could change the template files [`Gemfile.tt`](https://github.com/rubygems/bundler/blob/master/lib/bundler/templates/newgem/Gemfile.tt) and [newgem.gemspec.tt](https://github.com/rubygems/bundler/blob/master/lib/bundler/templates/newgem/newgem.gemspec.tt) according to your needs. For example you could use this `Gemfile.tt`:

```rb
source "https://rubygems.org"

# Specify your gem's dependencies in <%= config[:name] %>.gemspec
gemspec
```

To find where the template files are you could use this shell command:

```sh
find $(dirname $(gem which -g bundler)) -name Gemfile.tt
```

Comment: Good to know. But still not clear why 'rspec' is not declared in a test or development scope.